# httparty response interpretation in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, httparty

I have a service that returns (in an XML format) a list of networks. That list could be comprised of 1 network or 2+ networks.

This is for example what is returned from a REST client where there is 1 network

```
<Vdc status="1" name="VDC1" id="urn:vcloud:vdc:c66c192a-b58e-468c-bca8-4bfd5657f2ff" href= "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/vdc/c66c192a-b58e-468c-bca8-4bfd5657f2ff" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vdc+xml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5 http://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd">
<AvailableNetworks>
<Network href= "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/4c5703e5-4365-4408-8f8e-12ec3bfc716f" name="default-routed-network" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"/>
</AvailableNetworks>
</Vdc>
```

And this is what is returned when there are 2 networks:

```
<Vdc status="1" name="massimo" id="urn:vcloud:vdc:ec16bc23-659d-48b8-af7d-9dda6584122e" href= "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/vdc/ec16bc23-659d-48b8-af7d-9dda6584122e" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vdc+xml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5 http://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd">
<AvailableNetworks>
<Network href= "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/762cc1c7-d9cc-4eb8-9dfd-17bbc04ca607" name="default-routed-network" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"/>
<Network href= "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/8cf5b475-901b-4bed-9506-b394ed2505c2" name="massimo-network" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"/>
</AvailableNetworks>
</Vdc>
```

If I use httparty to query the service this is what I get in the response when there is 1 network:

```
"AvailableNetworks" => {
        "Network" => {
            "href" => "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/4c5703e5-4365-4408-8f8e-12ec3bfc716f",
            "name" => "default-routed-network",
            "type" => "application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"
        }
    },
```

and this is what I get when there are 2 networks:

```
 "AvailableNetworks" => {
        "Network" => [
            [0] {
                "href" => "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/762cc1c7-d9cc-4eb8-9dfd-17bbc04ca607",
                "name" => "default-routed-network",
                "type" => "application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"
            },
            [1] {
                "href" => "https://uk-slough-1-6.vchs.vmware.com/api/compute/api/network/8cf5b475-901b-4bed-9506-b394ed2505c2",
                "name" => "massimo-network",
                "type" => "application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml"
            }
        ]
    },
```

This makes managing the response very difficult. At the moment what I do is as follow: I run a check to see if `response["Vdc"]["Networks"]` is an array and if it is I iterate for its length and treat all its elements as independent hash items. If it is not an array I deal with `response["Vdc"]["Networks"]` as if it was a hash.

Is there a better way to deal with this and to avoid to check? Ideally I'd like to see `response["Vdc"]["Networks"]` as always being an array (if there is 1 network I'd like to see an array with 1 element).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because httparty and its underlying XML parser don't understand the API schema, it will be created simply as a key value pair. This code will coerce the element to be an array if it is not already.

```
result["Vdc"]["AvailableNetworks"]["Network"] = [result["Vdc"]["AvailableNetworks"]["Network"]] unless result["Vdc"]["AvailableNetworks"]["Network"].is_a? Array
```